# No of consumers getting reduced as time is passed in Torquebox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jboss7.x, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I have a rails app which is on torquebox. I am using processors to some background jobs. I have alloted 4 workers to that processor.

```
queues:
  /queue/company:

messaging:
  /queue/company:
    CompanyWorker:
      concurrency: 4
```

The `CompanyWorker` is doing a call to some other sites. It may raise an exception but I have caught inside by worker itself. But as I noticed my log I have seen that no. of threads/workers are reduced as time passes. After 10-15 hours only one thread/processor is working. How do I stop this from happening and keep all 4 workers/processors alive.

After Some hours I only see

```
22:29:40,945 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-124 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1460048766))
```

only thread 124 doing its job,

And after few hours I need to restart the server to get all 4 processors working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your processors are completing, i.e. not hanging indefinitely. Also make sure you're catching Throwable so nothing thrown escapes.

Comment: can you add an example of catching throwable